# Receiver for Internet data

Tags: wireless, internet

Can we use the same technology we use for radios to create a receiver which would catch Internet data?

Can we build a receiver which would be connected directly to the satellites?

And if those are not possible when you turn on the WiFi and start browsing your computer retrieves information in the form of EM waves. Can we build something that could collect these information?

Comment: Do you know how the Internet works?

Comment: Do you know how Wi-Fi works?

Comment: Yes, we can. What is your budget?

Comment: Just imagine the lonely satellites transmitting in vain, only to be defeated by our inability to build receivers.

Comment: "*... same technology we use for radios ...*" What kind? AM/FM or something else? We already use radio for WiFi and mobile. "*... connected directly to the satellites ...*" How would you connect directly to a satellite? "*... when you turn on the WiFi and start browsing your computer retrieves information in the form of EM waves. Can we build something that could collect these information?*" We already have. Your computer is doing it.

Comment: *Can we build a receiver which would be connected directly to the satellites?* - why do this when radio works usually so well and several thousand miles of cable to a satellite is unfeasible unless you plan on some inverted Jules Verne idea.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, wireless Internet is a thing, it's called [WiFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi).

And satellite-based Internet is a thing, too. There are many providers of such services.

But keep in mind that Internet in general requires two-way communication. It is not a broadcast service like radio and TV. Even watching or listening to streaming audio and video services requires two-way communication.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use the same technology we use for radios to create a receiver which would catch Internet data?

No, radio receivers only receive radio data.

However, Wi-Fi transmits Internet data over the radio.

So can we build a radio receiver that will receive Wi-Fi data? Well, yeah. They're called Wi-Fi modules. Your computer has one, how did you think it received Wi-Fi data?

> Can we build a receiver which would be connected directly to the satellites?

Do you have a long enough cable?

I'm not really sure what you're talking about, anyway. There are no satellites involved. Unless you have satellite Internet which means your Internet goes through a satellite. You'll know if you have that.

You could receive satellite Internet signals meant for other people who have satellite Internet, but they *should* be encrypted so there's no real point. (I don't know if they *are* encrypted - humans like to cut corners)

> And if those are not possible when you turn on the WiFi and start browsing your computer retrieves information in the form of EM waves. Can we build something that could collect these information?

Yes, it's called your computer. Specifically the Wi-Fi module (chip/card/whatever) in your computer.